# How to add a new rule to an existing CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, class, dynamic, stylesheet

In the code below i have illustrated what I am trying to achieve...
Altering an existing CSS class by adding a new rule to it.

```
<head>
<style> 

h4.icontitle
{font-size: 22pt;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

textpercent = 84;
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules.['h4.icontitle'].style.setProperty('-webkit-text-size-adjust', textpercent+'%', null);

</script>

<h4> hello </h4>

</body>
```

This is for a pre-process element of a site running on screens of different sizes.
The result will be...

```
h4.icontitle
{font-size: 22pt;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:84%;}
```

Which will be visible when inspecting the DOM.

Any ideas would be most welcome. Javascript only - no JQuery here...

SOLVED.

After a lot of trial and error, here is a working function that allows javascript to insert styles directly into the CSS

```
function changeCSS(typeAndClass, newRule, newValue)
{
    var thisCSS=document.styleSheets[0]
    var ruleSearch=thisCSS.cssRules? thisCSS.cssRules: thisCSS.rules
    for (i=0; i<ruleSearch.length; i++)
    {
        if(ruleSearch[i].selectorText==typeAndClass)
        {
            var target=ruleSearch[i]
            break;
        }
    }
    target.style[newRule] = newValue;
}
```

Called with

```
    changeCSS("h4.icontitle","backgroundColor", "green");
```

Hopefully others will find this a useful method to use variables within their CSS in pure javascript.

Comment: u want to alter css using javascript or jquery rite?

Comment: Why not jQuery or some similar library? `$('h4.icontitle').css('-webkit-text-size-adjust', textpercent+'%');`

Comment: Javascript only please. No libraries in this site (so far).

Comment: Solved. See edits to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put an example together that should suit your needs

DEMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/cS7WN/1/)

```
// this gets all h4 tags
var myList = document.getElementsByTagName("h4"); // get all p elements

// this loops through them until it finds one with the class 'icontitle' then it assigns the style to it
var i = 0;
while(i < myList.length) {
    if(myList[i].className == "icontitle") {
        myList[i].style.color="red";
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: The logic is identical, glad i could help.

Comment: Just to be clear, this answer is solving a slightly different problem: changing the css styles for a particular selector, rather than creating a different css rule.
The difference can be seen if you later add a new h4.icontitle element to the DOM.  In the answer TJS101 gives to his/her own question, the new element will have the changed style, while in this solution it would not.

Answer (score 4):

This function works perfectly for my site.

```
function changeCSS(typeAndClass, newRule, newValue)
{
    var thisCSS=document.styleSheets[0]
    var ruleSearch=thisCSS.cssRules? thisCSS.cssRules: thisCSS.rules
    for (i=0; i<ruleSearch.length; i++)
    {
        if(ruleSearch[i].selectorText==typeAndClass)
        {
            var target=ruleSearch[i]
            break;
        }
    }
    target.style[newRule] = newValue;
}
```

Called with

```
    changeCSS("h4.icontitle","backgroundColor", "green");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
Use this to update style tag contents
**/
var css = 'h1 { background: grey; }',
head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

To work with elements within body use querySelector to target elements upon their CSS identifier. This should help you
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

```
var el = document.querySelector(".icontitle");
el.setAttribute("style","-webkit-text-size-adjust:84%");
```

Or you can prepare a css snippet and use it conditionally ex: if "new_css" is the new change then

```
/**css code in style tag**/
.icontitle{

  /**style at initial stage**/

}
.icontitle-new-modified{

 /**modified css style at later stage**/

}

//after a condition is satisfied
el.setAttribute("class","icontitle-new-modified");
```

Comment: document.querySelector(".icontitle") returns a null value. Are you sure that is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Ah. It is targeting elements in the body, not the CSS. I need this to alter the CSS in the HEAD. Please see the desired output in the original question.

Comment: You can create alternate css snippets, and use querySelector to change the class attribute of elements, in that way you are even managing your code and you can achieve what you want.

Comment: The elements are not defined. The content is delivered dynamically. I need to alter the CSS not the element style.

Comment: I have modified answer please check, hope it helps

Comment: You put me on the right track. I have left a fully working function to do what I want in my edits to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try this piece of code

```
$('h4.icontitle').css('-webkit-text-size-adjust','84%');
```

Comment: I am not using JQuery. Just JS. This looks great. What is the JS Equivalent?

Comment: What's important and complicated with plain JS is this: `$('h4.icontitle')`. Why? You basically need to walk the whole DOM tree and find all h4 tags that have that class and build a list of them.

Comment: See code snippet in original question. That's what I want to get working.

Comment: As with Vector's answer, this is not a solution to the same problem that TJS101 asked.  It will indeed set the style of all *current* h4.icontitle elements, but if new h4.icontitle elements are created later they will not pick up the style, the way they would if the css rule is changed.   Obviously this may or may not be important, depending on the scenario.